# Passing api management policy to arm template via 'Azure resource group deployment' task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I'm using "Azure resource group deployment task" in the azure pipeline to deploy API management service. And one of my parameters is "policy content" (xml content passing like a string).

What I see right now this task converts this string:

```
"<policies>
    <inbound>
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="RESOURCE_URL_ID" output-token-variable-name="msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["msi-access-token"])</value>
        </set-header>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Product != null)">
                <set-header name="Header-Tenant-Id" exists-action="override">
                    <value>@(context.Product.Name)</value>
                </set-header>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request/>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
    </on-error>
</policies>"
```

to this:

```
"'<policies>\t<inbound>\t\t<authentication-managed-identity resource=\"api://09a361fe-cd46-4609-a112-86725e4b3338\" output-token-variable-name=\"msi-access-token\" ignore-error=\"false\" />\t\t<set-header name=\"Authorization\" exists-action=\"override\">\t\t\t<value>@(\"Bearer \" + (string)context.Variables[\"msi-access-token\"])</value>\t\t</set-header>\t\t<choose>\t\t\t<when condition=\"@(context.Product != null)\">\t\t\t\t<set-header name=\"Header-Tenant-Id\" exists-action=\"override\">\t\t\t\t\t<value>@(context.Product.Name)</value>\t\t\t\t</set-header>\t\t\t</when>\t\t</choose>\t</inbound>\t<backend>\t\t<forward-request />\t</backend>\t<outbound>\t</outbound>\t<on-error>\t\t<set-header name=\"ErrorMessage\" exists-action=\"override\">\t\t\t<value>@(context.LastError.Message)</value>\t\t</set-header>\t\t<set-header name=\"ErrorStatusCode\" exists-action=\"override\">\t\t\t<value>@(context.Response.StatusCode.ToString())</value>\t\t</set-header>\t</on-error></policies>'"
```

It adds a single quote to the start and to the end of the input string.
Due to this behavior, I have this error: **"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."** and deployment fails.

I pass this parameter via "Override template parameters" `-apimPolicy "$(ApimServicePolicy)"`
Any thoughts on how to skip these single quotes adding?

Comment: You can try to convert parameter.xml  to parameter.json . Azure resource group deployment task does not support parsing XML file.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT The best solution which was found on the internet is to put all APIM's policies in one line and not to pass it thought deployment task. But on another hand, it quite difficult to add some changes to it because of one-line formating. The problem was that we tried to convert XML to paramter.json when it doesn't supported. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, the problem could be `parameter.xml` file cannot be parsed by Azure resource group deployment task. Azure resource group deployment task only supports parsing parameter files in `json` format.

You can search out many Convert XML To JSON tools through Google, for example:

```
{
   "policies": {
      "inbound": {
         "authentication-managed-identity": {
            "_resource": "RESOURCE_URL_ID",
            "_output-token-variable-name": "msi-access-token",
            "_ignore-error": "false"
         },
         "set-header": {
            "value": "@(\"Bearer \" + (string)context.Variables[\"msi-access-token\"])",
            "_name": "Authorization",
            "_exists-action": "override"
         },
         "choose": {
            "when": {
               "set-header": {
                  "value": "@(context.Product.Name)",
                  "_name": "Header-Tenant-Id",
                  "_exists-action": "override"
               },
               "_condition": "@(context.Product != null)"
            }
         }
      },
      "backend": {
         "forward-request": ""
      },
      "outbound": "",
      "on-error": ""
   }
}
```

This is also stated in the task [document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV2/README.md), please refer to the part as shown below.

[image]